# How to use WebRTC on android

Tags: webrtc

i am trying to make a video chat application for android using webRTC and i can't seem to get a good tutorial online, could someone walk me though or direct me to an online tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the sample app in the webrtc repo?

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp/README